# How to compare two lists efficiency

Tags: python

I convert two csv files to a lists. I need to compare the two lists and create an new one with the difference between the two lists.

I tried the set function but it seems that it does not work !

Any suggestion to do it  an efficient way ?

My code :

```
import csv
with open('Mylist2.csv','r') as t1, open('VerizonList.csv','r') as t2:
    fileone = csv.reader(t1)
    filetwo = csv.reader(t2)
    list1 = list(fileone)
    list2 = list(filetwo)

newone = set(list1).difference(list2)
```

Thank you in advance (i'm begineer ^^)

Comment: This will be easier to answer if you share a sample of the 2 lists

Comment: How big is the csv? How do you want to get the difference? list1-list2 always or do you need symmetric difference?

Comment: Can you share the two lists? What do you mean by difference? Every element in list1 that is not in list2? Elements in list2 not in list1? Both?

Comment: *Does not work* is not really enough to go on. Please show us the output you are getting (or a sample of it) and what you expect to see.

Comment: two lists of IP adresses : example : list1 = ['10.10.2.1', '10.10.2.2', '10.10.2.3'] and list2 = ['10.10.2.1', '10.10.2.2']. I'm looking to create a new list that include the difference between list1 and list2. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Define what you mean by difference: elements on l1 not on l2, the other way around or both...

Comment: Mstaino yes. So i want to get a new list after comparing list1 and lsit2 ===================> list 3 =['10.10.2.3']

Comment: This has a one line solution. `[item for item in first_list if item not in second_list] + [item for item in second_list if item not in first_list]`

Comment: If you don't care about preserving their order, convert them to sets and use the set difference notation: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-set-difference/

Comment: Thanks for your help. I get my expected result.